# How can I schedule enable/disable an element in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, disabled-input

Consider 4 buttons on a page labeled Button A, Button B, Button C and Button D.
By clicking each button, user redirects to another page. However, I want each button be active on a predefined date and time and the hover color of that button be green when it's activated. For instant, button A is activate on  June 23, 2019 at 2:00 pm till 4:00 pm. It's color is green and color of other buttons are red and they are deactivated. In next predefined time, button B is green and activated and so on.
Is it possible using Javascript ?

Update:
Please help me find out how the code below works with this topology:

```
HTML:
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <h1>How this code works?</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">ITEM1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ITEM2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">ITEM3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>  
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS:
    * { box-sizing:border-box; }
    body { color:#222; padding:1em 2em; background:#eee; font:13px/1.4 'open sans', sans-serif; }
    h1, h2 { margin:0 0 .5em; line-height:1.2; font-family:'open sans condensed', sans-serif; }
    h1 { color:#f90; text-transform:uppercase; } p { margin:1em 0; }
    a { color:#06c; -webkit-transition:.2s linear; transition:.2s linear; } a:hover { color:#07c; }
    footer { color:#888; clear:both; font-size:12px; margin:2em 0 0; text-align:center; } footer a { color:#444; }
    #wrap { margin:1em auto; padding:1.5em; background:#fff; box-shadow:0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2); }

```
#nav { background:#333; }
  #nav ul { padding:0; overflow:hidden; list-style:none; }
  #nav li { float:left; }
  #nav a { color:#fff; display:block; padding:.5em 2em; }
    #nav a:hover { background:#666; }
    #nav a.active { color:#222; background:#f90; }
      #nav a.active:hover {}
      #nav.over a.active { color:#fff; background:none; }
        #nav.over a.active:hover { background:#666; }
```

JavaScript:

```
let timeToActivate = (new Date("June 23, 2019 14:00:00")).getTime();
let timeToDeActivate = (new Date("June 24, 2019 16:00:00")).getTime();
let currTime = Date.now();
var NewClass = document.querySelector("#nav a");

if(currTime > timeToActivate && currTime < timeToDeActivate){
    // Write Code To Activate Button
    NewClass.setAttribute("class","active");
}else if(currTime < timeToActivate){
NewClass.setAttribute("class","active");


    setTimeout(() => {

         // write code to activate button

         // To Deactivate button on 4pm
         setTimeout(() => {

              // write code to deactivate button

         }, timeToDeActivate - Date.now())

    }, timeToActivate - currDate);
}
```

**UPDATE 2: Solution using jquery**
Here is the working solution. I just updated the post in case anyone else has the same purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>   
 btna = [
    {
      "id":"#btn123",
      "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4849-p4850-o1",
      'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
      'closeTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
    },
    {
      "id":"#btn1234",
      "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4940-p4850-o2",
      'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
      'closeTime' : "June 25, 2019 14:00:00",
    },
    {
      "id":"#btn12345",
      "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4941-p4850-o3",
      'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
      'closeTime' : "June 28, 2019 14:00:00",
    }
  ]
  $(document).ready(function(){
    let openTime
    let closeTime
    let button
    let itemForm
    let now = Date.now();
    btna.map(function(item){
      openTime = (new Date(item.openTime)).getTime()
            closeTime = (new Date(item.closeTime)).getTime()
      button = $( item.id )
      itemForm = $( item.formId )
      if (closeTime > now && openTime < now ) {
        // Button in correct time period
        button.addClass("active")
        // if you don't want to auto hide form in page startup just comment out this line 
        itemForm.hide()
        button.click(function(){
           $( item.formId ).toggle(250)
        })
      }else{
        // Button is'nt in its time period
        button.addClass("ex1")
        itemForm.hide()
      }
    })
  })</script>
```

Comment: you can use setTimeout function

Comment: yes as @HienNguyen suggested you can use setTimeout(() => { //activate code here }, (new Date("Date/Time You To Activate it")) - Date.now())

Comment: I think you should run that code every second or ever 5-10 second cause time is changing every second and you code runs only on page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make buttons deactivated by default then,

```
let timeToActivate = (new Date("June 23, 2019 14:00:00")).getTime();
let timeToDeActivate = (new Date("June 23, 2019 16:00:00")).getTime();
let currTime = Date.now();

if(currTime > timeToActivate && currTime < timeToDeActivate){
    // Write Code To Activate Button
}else if(currTime < timeToActivate){

    // To Activate on 2pm
    setTimeout(() => {

         // write code to activate button

         // To Deactivate button on 4pm
         setTimeout(() => {

              // write code to deactivate button

         }, timeToDeActivate - Date.now())

    }, timeToActivate - currTime);
}
```

As per your updated question, i've created a fiddle, check it its working

https://jsfiddle.net/Abhay_Sehgal20/cy2jqmpu/5/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to apply your suggested solution. However, I'm unable to fix it. Would you please let me know what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: @Majid, i've created a fiddle check from above link

Comment: test it by passing timeToActivate less than current time it will show you green button, then test it by passing timeToActivate some x seconds greater than current time you will see blue button which will get change after x seconds to green similarly you can test timeToDeactivate also

Comment: Do upvote and accept the answer if this worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, I have several btn elements which I named them as btn1, btn2 ,...,and I have to repeat it for each element, Which leads to have many javascript tags, Do you know how I can place them in one tag may be in a "for" loop ? the challenge is each btn should be active in different date and time !

Comment: For multiple buttons you can use array of objects each object will have timeToActivate and timeToDeactivate for each button